# Html tag to obtain different forms

Tags: html, css, forms

I would like implement a sort of choice using only Html and Css. I need to obtain a field where my user makes a choise and the latter leads to different forms. Precisely if  my user decides to change his password will appear two input fields, or if he decides to change his information about his place of residence will appear four input field. Is possible this by using only Html and Css?

Comment: I made up one different form for every singular information. And i was looking for a way to have a sort of select that shows only the selected form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use a javascript library to do this bud. Don't think you can trigger this with just html and css. Though i may be wrong.

Comment: It's my same fear. But i can't use Js because my Web-App must work also when Javascript is disabled.

Comment: Then if JS is disabled you should perhaps create multiple forms but link to them via an anchor tag which are hidden via css by default, and maybe using PHP to add a styling tag of say style="display: block"  to show the correct one when selected? I'm unsure of a more logical way than this, but that's my idea haha

Comment: Yes, it's a valid solution. I think that i will use it! Thanks a lot.